# Use maven to pack modules into an ear module

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, pom.xml

I have a project divided into modules/sub-projects.

Root
 - module jar (used to contain ejb)
 - module war (used to contain web app)
 - module ear (used to pack the two aforementioned modules into one deployable unit)

Without using maven we should:

- Build the jar and war projects separately and then
  pack them in a ear.

I'm new to Maven but in my understanding Maven is used to manage this process
on behalf of the developer.

My project in term of maven is structured in the following way:

ROOT
 parent-pom.xml
 - jar-pom.xml
 - war-pom.xml
 - ear-pom.xml

My question is how do we tell maven to pack the jar and war module into a .ear
project, wich pom.xml should host this information ?

**Edit**:

The following is my project structure

[image]

Comment: Do you really have a file `ear-pom.xml`? You need to add a dependency to both the JAR and the WAR artifact inside the EAR POM.

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate a little bit, I'm very new to maven..;)

Comment: Could you post your exact project structure?

Comment: done, I hope that helps.

Comment: Look at the https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin. This is a really broad question.

Answer (score 0):

Find the sample  pom.xml under ear project to build ear

Add

```
<packaging>ear</packaging>
```

Add Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId><Your api Jar Group Id></groupId>
    <artifactId><Your API artifact Id></artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
     <type>ejb</type>
</dependency>
```

Add build plugin

```
<build>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId
     <configuration>
      <version>6</version>
      <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
      <modules>
        <ejbModule>
          <groupId><Your EJB Module Group Id></groupId>
          <artifactId><Your EJB Module Artifact Id></artifactId>
        </ejbModule>
      </modules>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```